# jQuery document.ready causing issues after v3.0

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using jQuery 3.0.0.

I also have bundling software installed, so I bundle everything into one (not so) big file and serve it **async**.

My bundle file looks like this:

```
vendor/jQuery.3.0.0.min.js
// Other jQuery-ui etc.

// My own stuff
CookieNotice.js
// more stuff

InitReady.js
```

The aim of **InitReady.js** is to initialise certain functions, which are encapsulated in **document.ready** - it looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    cookieNotice.init();
});
```

All of this works in my current version of jQuery.

However, I've since tried to upgrade jQuery versions - first I looked at version 3.4.1, then 3.5.1. but I get a couple of jQuery errors (strangely, only when using the compressed file). This is the error:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: a is not a function TypeError: a is not a function
    at k (http://localhost:2602/assets/scripts/v-200519131800/Init.min.js:1:39990) undefined
```

As the uncompressed version of jQuery throws no obvious errors, I've traced it back in a pretty crude way, and found that if I removed the `document.ready`from **InitReady.js** the error disappeared - even if I leave the contents intact.

Also, if I leave the document.ready without any contents, the error persists.

From what I can see, things still seem to work without the document.ready but I'm unsure whether this is just a fluke or not.

Can anyone offer advice on what I'm seeing and potentially what I need to do to fix it.

Comment: This looks like a minification error. What do you use for minification? For instance Microsoft's Ajaxmin does not support ES2015 syntax;

Comment: Really impossible, I would make sure you have map files in place and break on errors. And debug.

Comment: @PoulBak I'm using Asp.Net so using quite an old minifier/compressor - ServiceStack. New projects use WebEssentials but the way they approach bundling is very different so will be a real pain to move over.

Comment: So more likely a *bundling* issue with already min'd files (jquery.min)?  With asp.net, you turn off the bundling temporarily to see if that is the problem.